# Bootstrap Table with each row as collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an application.

The requirement is I have a table and each row is populated via ng-repeat from json data.

While clicking on each row the row has to expand and there would be an nested table and clicking on any row on nested table will expand that row and there would be another nested table.

Till now I am not even able to get the first nested table to open while clicking on row.

Ideally I prefer the each nested view to have a separate html template, but for simplicity I am trying with normal collapsible div.

Here is my code.

```html
<div class="col col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Level</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#endpoints" data-ng-repeat="data in datafromservice">
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.status}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.description}}</td>
        <td>{{data.size}}</td>
        <td>{{data.level}}</td>
        <!-- edit button -->
        <td class="edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
        </td>
        <!-- button button -->
        <td class="delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <div class="collapse" id="endpoints">
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```

I must be missing something very obvious, and I am not able to figure out.

Comment: DIVs are not allowed inside TABLE.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Even if I keep the div outside it is not working.
Here is a simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g5kjghcp/

Comment: You haven't load jquery. Open console and check the error message.

Comment: Would something like this work? http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/feature-panels-with-collapse